# undefined index text fields php database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

when i enter the url(//login.php) after login it gives undefined index on t1 and t2.
how can i use session on this page
index.php

```
        <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"></head>
    <h1>Login Here</h1>
    <form name="f1" action="login.php" method="post">
    <table border="1">
    <tr><td>username</td><td><input type="text" name="t1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>password</td><td><input type="password" name="t2"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="login"></td>
    <td class="error"><?php if(isset($_GET['wrong_detial'])){
        echo "RE-ENTER username and password !! "; }?>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

this is login.php

```
     <?php
    include "db/db.php";
    $user=$_POST['t1'];
    $pass=$_POST['t2'];
     $result=mysql_query("select * from registor where username='$user' and password='$pass' ")or die(mysql_error());
    $row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
    ?>
    <h1>Welcome Mr. <?php echo $user;?></h1>
   <?php
    if(!$user == $row[1] || !$pass ==$row[2]){     //if username or password not matched with database
        header("location:account.php?wrong_detial");
    }
    else{
        if($user == 'admin'){     //if admin login
    ?>
    <table border="1">
    <tr><td>User ID</td><td>Username</td><td>Password</td><td>Email-ID</td><td>delete</td></tr>
    <?php
   $admin_result=mysql_query("select * from registor");
    while($admin_db=mysql_fetch_row($admin_result)){
        ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $admin_db[0];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $admin_db[1];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $admin_db[2];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $admin_db[3];?></td>
    <td id="div1">
    <a href="delete.php?delete=<?php echo $admin_db[1];?>" id="<?php echo $admin_db[1];?>">Delete</a> <!-- Deleting single record-->
    <?php   if(isset($_GET['user_del'])){
    echo "record deleted";
    }
        ?>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </table>
    <?php }
```

this is error
Notice: Undefined index: t1 in C:\wamp\www\12dec\core\login.php on line 8
Notice: Undefined index: t2 in C:\wamp\www\12dec\core\login.php on line 9

all is working  fine .but when i re-enter the url it gives this error. and how to fix this

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` show?

Comment: Are you entering the URL `login.php`? This script needs to be called from the form so it gets the POST parameters, you can't access it directly.

Comment: var_dump($_POST) shows= array (size=0)
  empty

Comment: i am working on localhost .i enter url= http://localhost/12dec/core/login.php.
error is  occurs when i enter the url address bar again

Comment: Like I said, that script is designed to be used from a form, not entered directly. You should enter `index.php`, not `login.php`.

Comment: If you enter it directly, where do you expect it to get the username and password from? That's why you're getting undefined index, because the username and password should be in t1 and t2, but you haven't supplied them.

Comment: if i enter index.php its again shows to login

Comment: If you run login.php without giving it valid credentials, it will go back to `index.php` anyway. So what's the difference? What are you expecting to happen when you enter `login.php` directly?

Comment: suppose i login.. it takes me to login.php page and shows me records.
but if i enter after clicking on addres bar.it gives this error.
how can i fixed it.I understand with your words that the post value is on index.php .how to display records in this criteria ..thanks friend

Comment: That's because you went through `index.php` to login, and it sends the username and password from the form. If you don't go through the form, there's no username and password. Maybe you need to learn about session variables and use that.

Comment: okey thanks @ barmar..i'll work with session.
thanks alot for you comments..:)

Answer (score 0):

In your `login.php` script , try changing

```
$user=$_POST['t1'];
$pass=$_POST['t2'];
```

to

```
$user = isset( $_POST['t1'] ) ? $_POST['t1'] : '';
$pass = isset( $_POST['t2'] ) ? $_POST['t2'] : '';
```

and then handle blank `$user` and/or blank `$pass` .

If either `$user` is blank or `$pass` is blank , either you can display a message to the user or display the login page which seems to be `index.php` in your case .

Comment: i used this .. but not working.how can i use session on this page

Comment: Could you explain more so that I understand what is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

it happened because the $_POST haven't index named 't1' or 't2', you can try ternary operation like this :

```
<?php
$user = isset($_POST['t1']) ? $_POST['t1'] : '';
$pass = isset($_POST['t2']) ? $_POST['t2'] : '';
```

it means like this :

```
if (isset($_POST['t1'])) {
    $user = $_POST['t1'];
} else {
    $user = '';
}
```